# How to set Fragment Textview from the activity it's shown on

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have `TestsFragment` that `extends` from `Fragment`.
in the layout of this `Fragment` there is a `TextView` (id: textview)
There is an `Activity` called `MainActivity`: this `Activity` contain a `FrameLayout` that shows the `Fragment`
I want to set the textview Text `onCreate` `MainActivity` for that I guess I need the view of this `Fragment`

I have tried this code (OnCreate - MainActivity):

```
Fragment fragment = new TestsFragment();
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_tests, null);
TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setText("text changed!");
```

But it doesn't work (No error the text just not chaning)

so can you help me with that ?
If there any code you need please tell !

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
Fragment testsFragment, signsFragment, practiceFragment, accountFragment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);


    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new TestsFragment(), "TestsFragment").commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new SignsFragment()).commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    testsFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TestsFragment");
    if(testsFragment != null){
        TextView textView = testsFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textView.setText("Text Changed!");
    }
}



private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_signs:
                selectedFragment = new SignsFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_tests:
                selectedFragment = testsFragment;
                break;

            case R.id.nav_practice:
                selectedFragment = new PracticeFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_account:
                selectedFragment = new AccountFragment();
                break;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
        return true;
    }
};
}
```

fragments_tests.xml(layout):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#007AFF" android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_tests"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:paddingHorizontal="5dp">


</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="text not changed"
    android:id="@+id/textview"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

- When users click on each menu item, you always create a new fragment, this is not a good user experience, because when users switch between menu items, they always see a new screen not the screen when they leave before. For example, in `SignsFragment`, there is an `EditText` to let users enter their name as "Bob", when they switch to `AccountFragment` and switch back to `SignsFragment`, the `EditText` will be empty (but users expect to see "Bob").
- To prevent this behavior, we will use `addToBackStack()` method, so the `FragmentManager` will keep a reference to all the created fragments. If the fragment does not exist in `FragmentManager`, it will create a new one, otherwise, it will reuse the existing one.

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG_SIGNS_FRAGMENT = "TAG_SIGNS_FRAGMENT";
    private static final String TAG_TESTS_FRAGMENT = "TAG_TESTS_FRAGMENT";
    private static final String TAG_PRACTICE_FRAGMENT = "TAG_PRACTICE_FRAGMENT";
    private static final String TAG_ACCOUNT_FRAGMENT = "TAG_ACCOUNT_FRAGMENT";

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_signs);
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            String tag = null;

            // Find the tag of fragment based on menu item position.
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_signs:
                    tag = TAG_SIGNS_FRAGMENT;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_tests:
                    tag = TAG_TESTS_FRAGMENT;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_practice:
                    tag = TAG_PRACTICE_FRAGMENT;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_account:
                    tag = TAG_ACCOUNT_FRAGMENT;
                    break;
            }

            // Find the fragment in FragmentManager.
            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

            // If the fragment is not existed, create a new instance of it, otherwise
            // use the existing one.
            if (fragment == null) {
                switch (tag) {
                    case TAG_SIGNS_FRAGMENT:
                        fragment = new SignsFragment();
                        break;
                    case TAG_TESTS_FRAGMENT:
                        fragment = new TestsFragment("text changed!");
                        break;
                    case TAG_PRACTICE_FRAGMENT:
                        fragment = new PracticeFragment();
                        break;
                    case TAG_ACCOUNT_FRAGMENT:
                        fragment = new AccountFragment();
                        break;
                }
            }
            // Show the fragment on screen.
            showFragment(fragment, tag);
            return true;
        }
    };

    private void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag)
                .addToBackStack(tag)
                .commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution will work +1. OP could also look into using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to greatly simplify communication between Activities and Fragments etc.

Comment: I ran the Fragment every time I click menu item and its only work for the first time and the seconds+ the Fragment appear as in the layout

Comment: @Yaniv I didn't catch your point. Could you elaborate it or you can post the code for Activity and Fragment. It will help me investiagate the problem faster.

Comment: I just did. Thank you very much for your caring I really appreciate that

Comment: @Yaniv let me investigate your code to find the root cause.

Comment: Is it not possible to set the text in the MainActivity?

Comment: It's possible, I updated my answer again.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that. I need to go for a 20 minutes and I will try it thank you any way!

REALLY! YOU'RE JUST GREAT!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226196/discussion-between-son-truong-and-yaniv).